# Can I launch Tilix in dropdown mode under Wayland?

Tags: wayland, tilix

I launch Tilix in dropdown mode (aka Quake mode) via a keyboard shortcut mapped to:

```
tilix --quake
```

After upgrading to Tilix 1.7.7 I get a regular window and a notification "Quake mode is not supported under Wayland, running as normal window".

Is there any way to still launch dropdown mode under Wayland?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this by binding the shortcut to:

```
env GDK_BACKEND=x11 tilix --quake
```

**References:**

From [release 1.7.7](https://github.com/gnunn1/tilix/releases/tag/1.7.7):

> ...the other major change is that support for quake mode in Wayland has been dropped. It's turned out to be have far too many issues to support due to the limitations of Wayland around window positioning. Users who want to use quake mode in Wayland can do so by forcing the usage of the X11 backend with tilix via the environment variable GDK_BACKEND=x11.

And from [gnunn1/tilix#1314](https://github.com/gnunn1/tilix/issues/1314):

> I've had a look at resolving these issues and frankly I just don't think it's possible to have a perfect experience under Wayland without getting into writing Wayland extensions or something else equally exotic

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, i still get that it's not available in wayland.

Comment: It does work however, when i put the env `GDK_BACKEND=x11 tilix --quake` command into the drop down terminal from the drop down terminal extension.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to avoid using X11 on Wayland, so using Hyprland as my window manager, I've created a small script that mimics the quake effect on Wayland using hyprctl and workspace 10 to always keep the window there. The solution utilizes a session_name, allowing for multiple Tilix windows. It's only tested on zsh and Hyprland but could be adapted to i3wm or sway.

It require use jq to parse the ctl json.

The tilix.sh script:

```bash
#!/bin/zsh

PROCESS_NAME="tilix"
SESSION_NAME="guake"
TARGET_WORKSPACE="10"

if pgrep -f "$PROCESS_NAME" > /dev/null; then
    read ADDR FULLSCREEN <<<$(hyprctl clients -j | jq -r '.[] | select(.class == "tilix" and .title == "Tilix: '"${SESSION_NAME}"'") | "\(.address) \(.fullscreen)"')
    CURRENT_WORKSPACE=$(hyprctl activeworkspace -j | jq -r '.name')

    if [ -n "$ADDR" ]; then
        if [ "$FULLSCREEN" = "true" ]; then
            echo "Tilix is fullscreen; moving to workspace $TARGET_WORKSPACE and removing fullscreen"
            # If fullscreen, undo fullscreen and move to workspace 0, then back to the original
            hyprctl dispatch fullscreen 0 "address:$ADDR"
            hyprctl dispatch movetoworkspace "$TARGET_WORKSPACE,address:$ADDR"
            hyprctl dispatch workspace "$CURRENT_WORKSPACE"
        else
            echo "Tilix is not fullscreen; moving to current workspace and setting fullscreen"
            # If not fullscreen, bring to current workspace and set to fullscreen
            hyprctl dispatch movetoworkspace "$CURRENT_WORKSPACE,address:$ADDR"
            hyprctl dispatch fullscreen 1 "address:$ADDR"
        fi
    else
        echo "No Tilix window with title 'Tilix: $SESSION_NAME' found."
        echo "Creating Tilix $SESSION_NAME in fullscreen"
        tilix --full-screen -s "$SESSION_NAME" -e zsh -c "echo -ne '\033]0;$SESSION_NAME\007'; exec zsh"
    fi
fi
```

Set up a shortcut, in my case MOD + SPACE:

```bash
# .config/hypr/hyprland.conf
bind = $mainMod, SPACE, exec, /path/to/script/tilix.sh
```

It works well. It's the best solution I could make using Wayland, and maybe it can serve as an alternative to using the X11 backend for someone else.